# Deserialize xml element attributes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm admittedly learning here, and have made progress in serializing and deserialzing xml.

Question that I have is, how do I access the `URI` in the XML below?

```
<address href="/api/juniper/sd/address-management/addresses/98677" 
uri="/api/juniper/sd/address-management/addresses/98677">
  <name>Any-IPv4</name> 
  <address-type>ANY_IPV4</address-type>  
  <description>Predefined any-ipv4 address</description> 
  <host-name /> 
  <id>98677</id>  
</address>
```

Really not sure how to set that up in my class to deserialize it?

My class right now looks like:

```
[XmlRoot("address", Namespace = "")]
public class address
{
    string _name;
    string _editVersion;
    string _addressType;
    string _ipAddress;
    string _description;
    string _hostName;
    string _zone;
    string _addressVersion;
    string _definitionType;
    string _createdByUserName;
    string _lastModifiedByUser;
    string _createdTime;
    string _lastModifiedTime;
    string _id;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "edit-version")]
    public string editversion
    {
        get { return _editVersion; }
        set { _editVersion = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "address-type")]
    public string addresstype
    {
        get { return _addressType; }
        set { _addressType = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ip-address")]
    public string ipaddress
    {
        get { return _ipAddress; }
        set { _ipAddress = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
    public string description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "host-name")]
    public string hostname
    {
        get { return _hostName; }
        set { _hostName = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the [XmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) attribute. Have a look at [this SO entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330643/serialize-property-as-xml-attribute-in-element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`XmlAttributeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) attribute*

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string uri
{
    get { return _uri; }
    set { _uri = value; }
}
```

---

If you want to have it serialize it as [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), you'll have to do it with a separate property as `Uri` is non-serializable.

```
[XmlAttribute("uri")]
public string SerializedUri
{ 
    get
    {
        return uri.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        uri = new Uri(value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public Uri uri { get; set; }
```

With this usage, in-code you would read/write directly to the `Uri uri` property and ignore the `SerializedUri` property. When passed through the serializer it will ignore that property and instead use the `SerializedProperty` which will in turn manually serialize/deserialize the `Uri uri` property.

<sub>* (say that 3 times fast)</sub>

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll give that a shot.  Is there a way to prevent it from serializing, and only apply during deserialization?

Comment: Sorry Travis, I'm not sure if I understand. You mean you want to _read_ the "uri" values from the XML, but if you were to serialize/output XML, you do _not_ want the "uri" attribute written?

Comment: If that's the case, a _quick hack_ would be to have the `SerializedUri` get method return null instead: `public string SerializedUri { get { return null; } set { uri = new Uri(value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); } }`. The `XmlSerializer` omits any `null` values and won't include the attribute; however the setter will still execute when reading in any existing/legacy uri attributes.