# Xml Deserialization - Mapping Xml Attribute to Property?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

How do I go about deserializing a collection of Xml elements (all with the same element name, but with specific attributes) to an object?

Here's a snippet of the Xml:

```
<mibscalar name="lotOccupiedPct" link="http://localhost:8080/v1/mib/objs/lotOccupiedPct?type=xml">
<data index="1" value="0" counter="0"/>
</mibscalar>
<mibscalar name="gateStatusCloseThreshold" type="readonly" link="http://localhost:8080/v1/mib/objs/gateStatusCloseThreshold?type=xml">
<data index="1" value="90" counter="0"/>
</mibscalar>
<mibscalar name="gateStatusOpenThreshold" type="readonly" link="http://localhost:8080/v1/mib/objs/gateStatusOpenThreshold?type=xml">
<data index="1" value="70" counter="0"/>
</mibscalar>
```

And the corresponding properties in my class (in order):

```
public int CurrentOccupancyPercentage { get; set; }
public int CloseThresholdPercentage { get; set; }
public int OpenThresholdPercentage { get; set; }
```

I'm assuming there are some attributes I can add to the properties that can handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a class with properties using `XmlAttribute` and `XmlElement`. It will allow you to serialize and deserialize to a XML file.

Here is an example [Serialize Property as Xml Attribute in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330643/serialize-property-as-xml-attribute-in-element).