# c# serialize to xml my own type as attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have classes, something like this:

```
Class1:
  List<Class2> A;
  string B;

Class2:
  Class3 A2;
  string B2;

Class3:
  string A3;
  string B3;
```

And I would like serialize it to XML, which will be looking like this:

```
<Class1>
  <Class2 A3="x" B3="y" B2="z" />
  <Class2 A3="x2" B3="y2" B2="z2" />
  ...
  <B> abc </B>
</Class1>
```

When I set in Class2 fields as XmlAttribute, I get unhandler exception System.InvalidOperationException 
Is any way to do this?
EDIT: Ok, I give to less details. I have problem how to serialize my own types list which will be look like up. I can serialize this to xml like:

```
<Class1>
  <A>
    <Class2 B2="x">
      <Class3 A3="x" B3="x"/>
    </Class2>
    <Class2 B2="x">
      <Class3 A3="x" B3="x"/>
    </Class2>
  </A>
```

But I would like have class3 as attribute without name class 3 (only fields from this class) and I don't want have   to list, only listed elements have name Class2. I'm not sure it's understandable...

Comment: I guess the exception had a message and even may be an inner exception. can you post it? To serialize class members they have to be public! very important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize Property as Xml Attribute in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330643/serialize-property-as-xml-attribute-in-element)

Comment: I edit my question and add some details.

Comment: I guess you will have to build it by hand using [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or quick and dirty add `XmlIgnore` to the `Class3` property and reflect the child properties in `Class2`. But that is really just a quick and dirty way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move A3 and B3 props to Class2?

```
Class1:
 [XmlElement("Class2")]
 List<Class2> A;
 [XmlElement]
 string B;

Class2:
 [XmlAttribute]
 string A3;
 [XmlAttribute]
 string B3;
 [XmlAttribute]
 string B2;
```