# Serialization XML to C# for attributes doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

actually I'm trying to serialize an XMl file in C# and it's working good for elements but not for attributes
I get the attributes as an XML elements 
I've tried so many things : xmlAttribute, xmlAttribute  with XmlRoot..... 
but it's not working

here is an exemple of how I do it

```
 public class Book
 {
  [XmlAttribute("id")]
  public string id {get;set;}
 }
```

what I want :

```
<Book id="1"></Book >
```

what I got :

```
<Book>
   <id>1</id>
</Book>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you get and what you want instead as well as a part of code to serialize? Is `Book` used in collection? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11330643/1997232) may be helpful.

Comment: post sample xml and sample code which you tried so far

Comment: The name has to match the attribute name (id) including upper case lower case letters.   If it doesn't match then add the name in double quotes in the parenthesis.

Comment: @Sinatr I edit the content..thank you

Comment: @jdweng already tried it

Comment: Is book showing up in the xml output file?

Answer (score 0):

Using `XmlSerializer`, I got the desired result

```
var book = new Book() { id = "1"};

using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(book.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, book);
    Console.WriteLine(stringwriter.ToString());
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Book id="1" />
```

Comment: thnx for your respond , in fact what I want is to get the data directly from an xml file (I just give an exemple) so I'm using XmlSerializer but I don't wanna set the value of Id , it has to be taken directly from the file...all but the attributs works for me

Comment: confused. can you please paste the code which you tried