# Creating XML Response in C#

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I have created a REST Service which sends a response in XML. I have set the response format as XML and created the following Data Contracts:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class AuthorisationResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Variable[] Variables { get; set; }
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Variable
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

This works ok however the output of the XML is not formatted as I need it. It is showing like this:

```
<Variables>
        <Variable>
            <Name>SomeName1</Name>
            <Type>SomeType1</Type>
        </Variable>
</Variables>
```

But I want to show it like this:

```
 <Variables>
        <Variable Name="SomeName1" Type="SomeType1"/>
 </Variables>
```

Can anyone advise what I change to structure it how I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize Property as Xml Attribute in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330643/serialize-property-as-xml-attribute-in-element)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataContract XML serialization and XML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858798/datacontract-xml-serialization-and-xml-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `XmlAttribute` to the properties

```
[DataContract]
public class Variable
{
    [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: worked well but did need to add XmlSerializerFormat in my service contract,