# C# XmlSerialization: Serialize string with attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to serialize the following from C# classes/structures into xml:

XML sample:

```
<xml>
   <somename id="bla">content</somename>
</xml>
```

How can I achieve, that a string has an additional attribute called `id`?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330643/serialize-property-as-xml-attribute-in-element/11330786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="somename")]
    public class Somename {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="xml")]
    public class Xml {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="somename")]
        public Somename Somename { get; set; }
    }
```

Actually you can use this tool https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/