# How to serialize an item with an attribute without having child items in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am trying to generate this simplified xml snippet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<group>
  <name attr="yes">My name</name>
</group>
```

When I serialize the below code the attribute goes to the group but I want the attribute to go to the name.

```
// C# class
[XmlRoot("group", IsNullable = false)]
public class Test1
{

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string attr = "yes";
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name;
}
// Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<group attr="yes">
  <name>My name</name>
</group>
```

If I make the element name a class I can get the attribute in the right place, however, now I get an additional nested element name.

```
[XmlRoot("group", IsNullable = false)]
public class Test1
{

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public Test2 Name;
}

public class Test2 : Object
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string attr = "yes";

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name;
}
// Output
<group>
  <name attr="yes">
    <name>My name</name>
  </name>
</group>
```

Question is how can I get the attribute on my element name without having child items to the element?

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330643/serialize-property-as-xml-attribute-in-element)

Comment: If your name has attributes, it surely is some kind of a nested type, isn't it. So you cannot provide an attribute to some simple value. You can provide attributes only to classes, thus `name` should be its own class as well. From a class-view there's no difference between attributes and properties/fields.

Comment: This is what I see in you link <SomeStringElementName Value="testData" />
I would like  <SomeStringElementName Value="testData">some more text<SomeStringElementName>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to mark that `Name` property on `Test2` with an [`XmlText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute) instead of an `XmlElement`.

```
public class Test2
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string attr = "yes";

    [XmlText]
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works. @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I didn't mind the extra class. I just wanted the avoid the inner <name> element

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I've read `without having child items to the element?` as xml child items.

Comment: That's right, I didn't want child items in the xml.. I just need to conform to an existing file format